# Linq query with multiple OrderBy statements added in a loop

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I have a method in a webservice that has parameter with which users can decide how they want to order their results. This is a `List(Of String)` with the names of the fields in the order they want to sort them.

I know I can normally order on multiple columns by doing the following

```
Dim test = Bars.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Foo) _
               .ThenBy(Function(x) x.Bar) _
               .ThenBy(Function(x) x.Test)
```

However in this case this won't work since I can't chain the `ThenBy` function because I'm adding the sorting orders in a loop. To use `ThenBy` I need an `IOrderedQueryable` collection. This is how I would want it to work

```
Dim sortColumns = {"Foo", "Bar", "Test"}
Dim query = From b in Bars
For each column in sortColumns
    Select Case column
        Case "Foo"
            query = query.Orderby(Function(x) x.Foo)
        Case "Bar"
            query = query.Orderby(Function(x) x.Bar)
        Case "Test"
            query = query.Orderby(Function(x) x.Test)
    End Select
Next

Dim result = query.Select(Function(x) x.x).ToList()
Return result
```

This of course won't work because `OrderBy` will replace any previous ordering. The only solution I can think of is ordering the list on some other variable first so I already have an `IOrderedQueryable` collection but this just seems like the wrong approach.

```
Dim bars As New List(Of Bar)
Dim sortColumns = {"Foo", "Bar", "Test"}
Dim query = bars.Select(Function(x) New With {.Temp = 1, .x = x}) _
                .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Temp)

For Each column In sortColumns
    Select Case column
        Case "Foo"
            query = query.ThenBy(Function(x) x.x.Foo)
        Case "Bar"
            query = query.ThenBy(Function(x) x.x.Bar)
        Case "Test"
            query = query.ThenBy(Function(x) x.x.Test)
    End Select
Next

Dim result = query.Select(Function(x) x.x).ToList()
Return result
```

Comment: "OrderBy will replace any previous ordering".  Untrue.  OrderBy preserves the prior orderings... meaning: it is a stable re-ordering.  Also meaning: it uses the prior ordering to break ties in the current ordering.  So:  OrderBy(Foo).ThenBy(Bar).ThenBy(Test) is the same as OrderBy(Test).OrderBy(Bar).OrderBy(Foo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write your own extension method `OrderByOrThenBy` which checks whether the value is *already* an `IOrderedQueryable`, uses `ThenBy` if so and `OrderBy` otherwise. Slightly smelly, but not terribly hard to do.

EDIT: C# sample (untested):

```
public static class QueryableOrdering
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TElement> OrderByOrThenBy<TElement, TKey>
        (this IQueryable<TElement> source,
         Expression<Func<TElement, TKey>> ordering)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (ordering == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
        }
        var ordered = source as IOrderedQueryable<TElement>;
        return ordered == null ? source.OrderBy(ordering)
                               : ordered.ThenBy(ordering);
    }
}
```

Comment: A C# sample would be fine, I can do the conversion myself.

Comment: @FreekBuurman: Add the working VB.NET code as answer with reference to Jon's answer.

Comment: This wont work as ordered will never be not null. It will always convert to the IOrderedQueryable object. This is my revised code:

Comment: "It will always convert to the IOrderedQueryable object" - not if it's not already ordered it won't... an unordered `IQueryable<TElement>` won't implement `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByOrThenBy<T, TKey>
        (this IQueryable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> ordering)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (ordering == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
        }
        var ordered = source as IOrderedQueryable<T>;

        var test = source.Expression.Print().Split(".OrderBy"); ;

        if (test.Length < 3)
        {
            return source.OrderBy(ordering);
        }
        else
        {
            return ordered.ThenBy(ordering);
        }
    }
```